# Anyway to use scrollTop but retain the hashtag?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code:

```
$('#toc a').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $link = $(this).attr('href');

          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($link).offset().top - 10
          }, 1000 );
         
});
```

But would like it to keep the hashtag from the link in the web address. Is this possible with the code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#toc a').on('click', function(e) {
    $link = $(this).attr('href');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($link).offset().top - 10
    }, 1000 );
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it didn't really work. Although it added the hashtag to the URL, it didn't actually animate.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - your fiddle uses my code, but when testing it seems the prevent default can just be removed, so lets try that.

Comment: @adeneo It doesn't actually animate to the location, like the original code does.

Comment: @adeneo The code I used in my question. It currently animates to the targeted location, but doesn't include the hashtag. Your code does include the hashtag, but no longer animates.

Comment: @Richard It work but there is a little blinking that annoy me. In case you want to remove it, use this code : http://jsfiddle.net/p5m4w/2/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Ah very nice! Thank you!!