# jQuery Scroll Bottom

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, bookmarks

I searched this site but all I found is jQuery scrolling to top. How can I scroll to certain link or bookmark in `bottom`?

e.g. if I click a button: `<a href="page.php?#contact_us">Contact Us</a>` then it should scroll the page down to bookmark: `<a name="contact_us"></a>` with jQuery. How can I go about this?

Comment: `<a href="#contact_us">Contact Us</a>` will scroll to an element with that ID.

Comment: I know but I want it to be jQuery and smooth

Comment: Then use a [plugin](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo)

Comment: Is there anything simple? I actually do not want to clutter jquery codes in my site. I want simple smooth scrolling. Is there anythi9ng like this available?

Comment: Just use jQuery animate in an event handler, that's about easy as it gets, or switch to Opera, it animates scrolling?

Comment: Can you please give any solution or example for this `jQuery animate in event handler`? Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503288/anyway-to-use-scrolltop-but-retain-the-hashtag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code too:

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid){
   var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}

$(".link").on('click', function() {
   scrollToAnchor(this.id);
});
```

[Fiddle in action](http://jsfiddle.net/KFUww/)

Here `.link` is the class name of your anchor tag and `id1, id2, id3..and so on` is the id for each anchor, and you have to bind an click event on anchor link and pass the id in the function named `scrollToAnchor(aid){...}` where `aid` is the param for id which is passed from the bound event.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery animateScroll (http://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll/), this plugin will add you smoth css3 effect.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="animatescroll.js">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="section-1">This is the element where you want to scroll to<div>

        // You may call the function like this
        <a onclick="$('[id-or-class-of-element]').animatescroll();">Go to Element</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/janfkowalski/gvgL7/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

    function scrollToByName(element) {
        // read target name, remove hash-tag
        var aTargetName = element.attr('href').split("#");
        var sTargetName = aTargetName[aTargetName.length-1];
        var jqTarget = $("a[name=" + sTargetName + "]");
        var sSpeed = "slow";

        // check if element exists
        if (jqTarget.length > 0) {
            // animate view to the target
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jqTarget.offset().top}, sSpeed);
        }
    }

    $('.scroll-trigger').on('click', function (event) {
        // prevent default 'jump'
        event.preventDefault();
        scrollToByName($(this));
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

with html

the trigger

```
<a href="page.php?#contact_us" class="scroll-trigger">Take me there.</a>
```

and the target

```
<a name="contact_us" href="#">Contact us</a>
```

Hope it works for you.